# c# error copy word document to textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, ms-word

I want to copy a Word document into a textbox in c# web application.
I added the Microsoft Word 10.0 Object Library. But I am getting an exception.

ERROR: The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass wordApp = new ApplicationClass();
object file = filePath;
object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(
            ref file, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
            ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
            ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
            ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);

doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
TextBox1.Text = doc.Content.Text;
doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
wordApp.Quit(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
```

Comment: What line do you get the exception on?

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(
            ref file, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
            ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
            ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
            ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.application.aspx) instead of [`ApplicationClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationclass.aspx)` (which is documented as 'Reserved for internal use'): see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2004/02/05/67872.aspx for details of why.

Comment: Did that. Still getting the same exception

Comment: Are you using the correct version of the Interop classes? I believe if the Interop version is different from the installed version it can cause problems. Also, is your file path valid? I just tried your code and it worked for me..